# Blank Screen- Microsoft Hololens emulater

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am new to MRTK & Unity development & need help to complete one POC.

To learn, I started with Hololens Far & Near cube example in Unity & wanted to test it in Hololens Emulator.

1. Created a Scene in Unity with two cubes.
2. Build & RUn in Unity with Target device as Holones for Windows Universal Platform.
3. Ran sln file in visual studio.
4. Hololens Emulator launched.

till here it's all good. But after this Problem starts.

1. Hololens is Stuck with a Black screen.
   [Black Screen with hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRjVr.png)
2. Breakpoint is triggered VS 2019.
   [Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0pyM.png)
3. When clicking on COntinue, Hololens shows 4 balls rotating.
   [4 balls rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpoQu.png)

I have no idea what happened to Cubes? & what is the meaning of this screen?

Regards,
Mayank Pande

Comment: May I ask have you tried to launch HoloLens 2 Emulator directly from Start Menu? Can you boot into the home screen of the Emulator and test hand actions?

Comment: Yes, when Launching the Hololens emulator directly from the Start menu works. Only when we trigger from VS2019 this issue occurs. Do you think something is wrong with the build?

Comment: Would you share a link for Far & Near cube example? I will try to reproduce this issue in my testing environment. What's the Unity version?

Comment: Sure: This is URL. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/

Unity Version : 2020.3.33f1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this issue.

- **HoloLens is stuck with a black screen.** -> In some projects this can be reproduced. The project is running with debugger with visual studio, HoloLens only shows 2 hand ray casts. It happens on both Emulator and physical devices, and this can be caused by corrupted MRTK profile. I create a new project and import the latest packages via Mixed Reality Feature Tools, then migrate assets to the new project to solve this issue.
- **Breakpoint is triggered VS 2019 ->** Is the breakpoint expected? Otherwise, you may try to turn off the first chance exception in VS 2019.
- **HoloLens shows 4 balls rotating** -> it is expected behavior when opening a project in Emulator. This animation indicates the resources are being loaded and it follows with Unity Splash screen, then the main scene of your Unity project.

Comment: Hi Seth, 
Thanks for the comments.
How much time does it take to open the project in Emulator? I have been trying for the last 20-25 minutes but the screen is not moving from the ball's animation.
I am using i7 processor with 24GB ram & Windows 11.
Regards,

Comment: Hi, would you take a look at the Windows Task Manager? The Emulator fluency relies on Memory and GPU. Do you have a dedicated graphic card in your test environment? and please make sure the GPU is working.